# Pinterest SDK authenticate permission fail

Tags: ios, authentication, pinterest

I am trying to pin an image to pinterest. However, when I tried to authenticate the user, it fails.

I am calling the following code on button click, which takes me to pinterest app and the authentication dialog is shown,

```
[[PDKClient sharedInstance] authenticateWithPermissions:@[PDKClientReadPublicPermissions,
                                                          PDKClientWritePublicPermissions,
                                                          PDKClientReadPrivatePermissions,
                                                          PDKClientWritePrivatePermissions,
                                                          PDKClientReadRelationshipsPermissions,
                                                          PDKClientWriteRelationshipsPermissions]
                                            withSuccess:^(PDKResponseObject *responseObject)
{
    PDKUser *user = [responseObject user];
    NSLog(@"%@ authenticated!", user.firstName);
} andFailure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"authentication failed: %@", error);
}];
```

Also nothing prints in the console. I am unable to access the responseObject inside the block.

[image]

when I click okay, the authentication fails.

[image]

I have no idea where I could be wrong. I followed the steps mentioned in the [pinteret/Developers](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/) . Can anyone guide me in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there is an error in the callback URL you are passing and /or which is provided by you in the app settings. Check that Url, as a recommendation.

Comment: when u say call back url do you mean the URL scheme for the pinterest ? or the url which starts with pin followed by the app key ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the URL scheme has an unwanted space character in the plist file.