# Pinterest API not accepting private scopes

Tags: php, api, laravel, oauth, pinterest

I am currently trying to write an application that works with private boards. I do know that the read_private and write_private scopes exist, and are getting displayed when showing the popup window (similar to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N94A.png, as shown by [Pinterest SDK authenticate permission fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34886806/1397894)).

Problem is though, that no private / secret boards are getting returned by the API and the token debugger does not show the scopes as well (as if their end simply does not store them).

The application is Laravel-based, using a Pinterest Socialite Provider, the scopes I am using are: `['read_public', 'write_public', 'read_private', 'write_private']`, communication to the API is all done through the server side.
The two composer packages I am using are "[mashuble/Pinterest-Socialite](https://github.com/mashuble/Pinterest-Socialite)" and "[dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP)"

As I would like to continue developing the application, but require the private board functionality, I am very dependent on that feature. Could it be that it's simply not public and beta-only? If that's the case, is there a way to opt-in to that feature?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: They are not supported by the API currently. We never officially supported private scopes, and eventually removed them altogether.

Comment: Will be there a time when they become available again? If not, I can already see myself writing some sort of website crawler…

Comment: It's not on the road map. And unfortunately crawling is against policy so I can't endorse it. 

Comment: Ah dang, I mainly wanted to use this for a small application used by our team, as Pinterest is lacking a lot of features we desperately need. Since it's tied to private boards I guess we have to look for something different :(

Comment: If you're using it strictly privately then crawling is probably fine.